# multi condition on different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, where-clause, having-clause

```
age | name     | course | score
_________________________
10  |James    | Math   | 10
10  |James    | Lab    | 15
12  |Oliver   | Math   | 15
13  |William  | Lab    | 13
```

I want select record where math >= 10 and lab >11
I write this query

```
select * from mytable
where (course='Math' and score>10) and  (course='Lab' and score>11)
```

but this query does not return any record.

I want this result

```
age | name     
____________
10  |James
```

where condition (math >= 10 and lab >11) is dynamically generate and perhaps has 2 condition or 100 or more...

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the names, then use aggregation and a having clause:

```
select name, age
from mytable
where (course = 'Math' and score > 10) or
      (course = 'Lab' and score > 11) 
group by name, age
having count(distinct course) = 2;
```

If you want the detailed records, use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (dense_rank() over (partition by name, age order by course asc) +
              dense_rank() over (partition by name, age order by course desc)
             ) as cnt_unique_courses
      from mytable t
      where (course = 'Math' and score > 10) or
            (course = 'Lab' and score > 11) 
     ) t
where cnt_unique_courses = 2;
```

SQL Server doesn't support `count(distinct)` as a window function.  But you can implement it by using `dense_rank()` twice.

Answer (score 2):

You query looks for records that satisfy both conditions at once - which cannot happen, since each record has a single course.

You want a condition that applies across rows having the same name, so this suggest aggregation instead:

```
select age, name 
from mytable
where course in ('Math', 'Lab')
group by age, name 
having
    max(case when course = 'Math' then score end) > 10
    and max(case when course = 'Lab' then score end) > 11
```

Answer (score 1):

If you formulate the problem as:

1. Select all unique (name, age) combinations
2. That have a row for course Math with a score >= 10
3. And that have a row for course Lab with a score > 11

Then you can translate this to something very similar in SQL:

```
select distinct t1.age, t1.name            -- unique combinations
from mytable t1
where exists ( select top 1 'x'            -- with a row math score >= 10
               from mytable t2
               where t2.name = t1.name
                 and t2.age = t1.age
                 and t2.course = 'math'
                 and t2.score >= 10 )
  and exists ( select top 1 'x'            -- with a row lab score > 11
               from mytable t3
               where t3.name = t1.name
                 and t3.age = t1.age
                 and t3.course = 'lab'
                 and t3.score > 11 );
```

Answer (score 0):

i think either your data or your condition is not right to get your output. though based on your condition you can separately used your condition and then use Intersect from both selection and get your filtered data. like the code below.

```
select Age,Name
from Table_1
where Course ='Math' and Score>=10
INTERSECT
select Age,Name
from Table_1
where Course ='Lab' and Score>11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write query using co-related subquery

```
select * from table_1 t1
    where score >11 and course ='lab' 
        and [name] in (select [name] from table_1 t2 where t1.[name] =t2.[name] and t1.age =t2.Age
        and t2.Score >=10 and course = 'Math')
```